# Rails scope for two time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get ActiveRecord to take in account two different time columns when building my scope. Right now I currently have:

```
new_cars = Car.where('car_created_at > ?', DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Stockholm").beginning_of_day)
```

Although I'm wanting the scope to also take in account another datetime field called `order_created_at` that follows the same rules of Europe/Stockholm time from beginning of day. As an example the end result SQL would ideally be something like this:

```sql
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" 
WHERE car_created_at > '2017-01-04 23:00:00' 
AND order_created_at > '2017-01-04 23:00:00' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`new_cars = Car.where('car_created_at > ? AND order_created_at > ?',` `DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Stockholm").beginning_of_day,` `DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Stockholm").beginning_of_day).order(id: :desc)`

Scope in model may look like:

```
scope :scope_name, -> { where('car_created_at > ? AND order_created_at > ?', DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Stockholm").beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Stockholm").beginning_of_day).order(id: :desc) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named placeholder to use the same argument twice:

```
date = DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Stockholm").beginning_of_day

new_cars = Car.where('car_created_at > :d AND order_created_at > :d', d: date)
```